# JMeter: Impossible to authenticate to a web application installed on Google Cloud Platform (GCP)

Tags: authentication, google-cloud-platform, jmeter

I am using JMeter for test performance (scaling up of connections) on a web application installed on a Google Cloud Platform (GCP).

My problem is that i can't authenticate and connect to this web app with JMeter.

By informing the url (https://my_web_app/login) in a test plan of JMeter and executing it, the result obtained is the connexion page of Google "Connect with your Google account" and not the login page of my web app (??).

How can i fix it to display the login page after authentication.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you "inform the url" in your browser? Let me guess, it automatically logs in using your current Google account. And what happens if you open the [private window](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/private-browsing-use-firefox-without-history) of the browser? You will get "Connect with your Google account" and not the login page.

1. JMeter always creates a clean session without any [Cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies)
2. [Well-behaved JMeter test must represent a real user using the real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) with 100% accuracy
3. So my expectation is that you need to implement [OAuth](https://www.oauth.com/) in your JMeter test, see [Signing in with Google](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/signing-in-with-google/) documentation chapter to get more information on what needs to be done from your end

Comment: Thank you. Absolutely, it connects directly if i inform url in my browser. I'm going to implement OAuth in my JMeter test plan.